# Grabbing specific data from an NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

all info is an __NSCFDictionary and I'm trying to get access just to the "ratings" key (the 3rd key). Any idea how I would go about grabbing the data from that field?

thanks for any help

my NSLog output from  `NSLog(@"allinfo description %@", allInfo.description);` is the following

```
allinfo description __NSCFDictionary
2012-03-14 11:50:28.056 Project[1173:11603] key = results -> obj = (
        {
        geometry =         {
            location =             {
                lat = "37.787565";
                lng = "-122.409593";
            };
        };
        icon = "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png";
        id = 6ea9093f35b4b0cf5cfa21b7dd40cb28d5aa5c5c;
        name = "Ruby Skye";
        rating = "3.4";
        reference = "CmRfAAAApDkEMtz2k6RQTmdeamVqY3KrXhpyzLoHc7EUDMCCUi3qD6PsYQE8qO2QjiUohpJIFtub_XUcYqPOt_LSUbILHjMzeHiacXDCSSKhybRB4VTy7-Oi72nibqwI3NmxnoxNEhB1I7mUheViH2V2ESkkmHbwGhS1G-LDz0PfJggIt8sZ2YO_BOILkQ";
        types =         (
            "night_club",
            bar,
            establishment
        );
        vicinity = "420 Mason Street, San Francisco";
    },
        {
        geometry =         {
            location =             {
                lat = "37.790237";
                lng = "-122.404676";
            };
        };
        icon = "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png";
        id = bf9fc5861d0ab56a337ded8d8c4b49e62709e3e5;
        name = "The Irish Bank";
        rating = "3.7";
        reference = "CnRlAAAAs0ggA4T1ri7H68CE7N1IWhfmY6EcED9pMNhvKhrFRUBFJLw73URrqoBpyGB585u7xDwtbmBV53eBj3rXpMlFI52OKz2Uv5-mIKT5pjFXCZJoTiux_SPoWQWFPCYoePyxhl6NFvmLWr-K-Jr7UnapWRIQNSuYGOFKgYg3yHTtoGq1KxoUqT4O-yIncvKbDJz8IygsdL7P2Go";
        types =         (
            bar,
            restaurant,
            food,
            establishment
        );
        vicinity = "10 Mark Lane, San Francisco";
    },
```

Comment: [yourDictionary objectForKey:@"rating"];

Comment: I tried that and it returns (null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a partial console snippet that looks like an `NSArray`; but it appears to be an `NSDictionary` when you log `[allInfo class]`.

Can you try this:

```
[allInfo enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"key = %@ -> obj = %@",key,obj);
}];
```

This should log the keys and objects and help elucidate the structure of the `NSDictionary` you are working with.

Update after OP added log output:

```
//    This should log all of the ratings
NSArray *results = [allInfo objectForKey:@"results"];
[results enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *ratingStr = [obj objectForKey:@"rating"];
    NSLog(@"rating = %@",ratingStr);
}];
```

Comment: the obj logs like the following. how do I access the ratings info for example? : obj = (
        {
        geometry =         {
            location =             {
                lat = "37.787565";
                lng = "-122.409593";
            };
        };
        icon = "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png";
        id = 6ea9093f35b4b0cf5cfa21b7dd40cb28d5aa5c5c;
        name = "Ruby Skye";
        rating = "3.4";

Comment: The `obj` log above is the log for `allInfo`?

Comment: Got it.  Now I understand the structure, I amended my answer above.  `allInfo` is an `NSDictionary` whose "results" key is an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects that contains a "ratings" key.

Answer (score 1):

The output (allinfo.description) looks like an NSArray with NSDictionaries inside of it but, [allinfo class] says it's an NSDictionary however there doesn't appear to be keys for each element. Apple's documentation specifies this about the keys when calling -description:

> If each key in the dictionary is an NSString object, the entries are listed in ascending order by key, otherwise the order in which the entries are listed is undefined.

I'd try using the -allKeys to get an NSArray of all the keys. If they aren't NSStrings then you'll need to figure out what it is in order to access the elements in this dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The log outPut you posted is an Array.You can access the "rating" by

```
NSString *ratingValue = [[allInfo.description objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"rating"];
```